# Force the button to call a function in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET Core.

I have saved some prices of products in my website, but prices must be changed regularly and I have to change all of them by click  on a button which calls the function to do mathematical calculating.

How can I force the button to call function in view of my controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can usually call on Page Load with something like this

```
var page = new Page();
//possibly do something with page
page.PageLoad(new object(), EventArgs.Empty);
//possibly do more stuff with page
```

Or even

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hiya", "alert('hi!')", true);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx for more info